# What is the approximate exchange rate of US Dollars against Units in MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

What is the approximate exchange rate of US Dollars against [Units](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Units) in MCU?

Comment: You can buy an ion cannon for 30 units at the Hub. Such a device would be worth 50 billion dollars if you tried to sell it to the US military

Comment: $U1:$225 - http://www.icollector.com/Guardians-of-the-Galaxy-Prop-Unit-Bank-Note_i21744753

Comment: @KSmarts - Well, not *US military boots*, at least.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such exchange rate. For such a thing to exist there must be trade between the US and the Andromeda galaxy, or entities within it that use Units, and there is plainly no such trade.

Answer (score -2):

Per your link 30 units for pawning a gun, if we assume the gun in question is an average weapon, a google search for the average gun pawn value returns a result of 305 USD so one unit equals approximately 10 USD.

The other values are subjective so cannot be used as a basis for exchange.

However this assumes that pawning an average weapon in the MCU on that particular planet equates to pawning an average weapon in the US.